# No such method memberName when building InvokeRequest for lambda function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jersey

I'm trying to create a request, in java, to call a lambda function locally.
When creating the request:

```
InvokeRequest request = InvokeRequest.builder()
                .functionName("examplelambda")
                .payload(SdkBytes.fromUtf8String("{\n" +
                        " \"Hello \": \"Paris\",\n" +
                        " \"countryCode\": \"FR\"\n" +
                        "}")).build();
```

it gives an error like this:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: software.amazon.awssdk.core.SdkField$Builder.memberName(Ljava/lang/String;)Lsoftware/amazon/awssdk/core/SdkField$Builder;
```

[image]

I'm using

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>lambda</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.124</version>
        </dependency>
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by downgrading software.amazon.awssdk.lambda dependency to 2.5.10

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>lambda</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.10</version>
</dependency>
```